# Update GUI from Config File in Qt

Tags: qt, config

I am making a GUI in which based on user login a certain number of buttons are supposed to be enabled and the rest disabled. I have to do this with the help of a config file. 
Can anyone please share any examples or references if they know.

Thank you :)

Comment: It's hard to say what you want to accomplish... If you're looking for a way to save settings, take a look at [QSettings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsettings.html#details)

Comment: I looked at it. I got how to read from ini files and set settings for color and all. However I am not able to understand how to apply the logic for buttons. For eg. In telkon every button has a hexadecimal argument which decides which property of the button is to be changed. Is their anything similar in Qt?

Comment: None that I know of... But what about simply saving values like: `settings.setValue("button1/enabled", true);` and then loading it: `ui->button1->setEnabled(settings.value("button1/enabled").toBool());`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Qt application that parses an `xml` file by validating it against a predefined `xsd` file.

The `xml` file had layout, grid, button text, and other various information for the user.

The goal of this was the end user could create his/her own `xml` file to custom configure their buttons.

What you need:

1. Define a data structure that will match your objective
2. Validate and test XML
3. Create a widget with whatever kind of layout you want. If you're doing buttons, you probably want to use a `QGrid`
4. Load the XML and configure your layout.